# Ошибки компиляциии

Tags: c++, кросс-компиляция

Я пытаюсь построить код в 13-й студии, который прекрасно работает под никсами, но под виндой ни в какую. Имеется ряд ошибок типа таких:

ошибка:

> Error 478 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'boost::shared_ptr' to 'bool'
>   C:\Natron\Engine\RotoDrawableItem.cpp 293 1   Engine

исходник:

```
bool ok = _imp->mergeNode = app->createNode(args);
```

ошибка:

> Error 11  error C2664: 'std::pair,KeyFrame>::pair(const
>   std::pair,KeyFrame> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair'
>   to 'const std::pair,KeyFrame>
>   &'    C:\Natron\Gui\CurveWidgetPrivate.cpp    691 1   Gui

исходник:

```
return std::make_pair( (CurveGui*)NULL,KeyFrame() );
```

ошибка:

> Error 13  error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from
>   'boost::shared_ptr' to 'bool' C:\Natron\Gui\DopeSheet.cpp 487 1   Gui

исходник:

```
bool DopeSheet::isPartOfGroup(DSNode *dsNode) const
{
    boost::shared_ptr<NodeGroup> parentGroup = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<NodeGroup>(dsNode->getInternalNode()->getGroup());

    return (parentGroup);
}
```

ошибка:

> Error 14  error C2664: 'void
>   std::TreeTmap_traits>::insert(std::initializer_listKty,Ty>>)'
>   : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair' to 'std::pairKty,Ty>
>   &&'   C:\Natron\Gui\DopeSheet.cpp 1442    1   Gui

исходник:

```
_imp->itemKnobMap.insert(TreeItemAndDSKnob(nameItem, dsKnob));
```

Напомню, что каким то магичеким образом этот код компилируют из под никсов.

[Ссылка](https://github.com/MrKepzie/Natron) на репозиторий с исходниками

Comment: Вы бы хоть используемые компиляторы указали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка

> cannot convert from 'boost::shared_ptr' to 'bool'

Абсолютно верна, т.к. в `boost::shared_ptr` `operator bool` помечен как `explicit`. Почему это компилируется в *nix? Видимо потому, что там используется старый компилятор(либо же не передаётся флаг использования C++11), который не поддерживает `explicit` у оператора преобразования типов и boost это грамотно обходит.

По поводу остальных ошибок сказать трудно: нужно больше кода, но, наверняка, они тоже присутствуют и должны быть исправлены.

---

Просто код нужно писать правильно, тогда таких проблем не будет. Начнём с первого куска:

```
bool ok = _imp->mergeNode = app->createNode(args);
assert(ok);
if (!ok) {
    throw std::logic_error("RotoDrawableItem::createNodes");
}
```

Переписываем на:

```
_imp->mergeNode = app->createNode(args);
assert(_imp->mergeNode);
if(!_imp->mergeNode) {
    throw std::logic_error("RotoDrawableItem::createNodes");
}
```

Тем более, что далее по коду так и делают, зачем тут добавил `ok` — не понятно

Второй кусок, меняем `return std::make_pair( (CurveGui*)NULL,KeyFrame() );`
на `return std::make_pair( boost::shared_ptr(),KeyFrame() );`

Третий кусок: меняем `return (parentGroup);` на `return static_cast<bool>(parentGroup);`

Четвертый кусок сложнее: там дело в том, что есть map c типом: `std::map<QTreeWidgetItem *, boost::shared_ptr<DSKnob> > DSTreeItemKnobMap;`, в который пытаются запихать `TreeItemAndDSKnob`, который имеет тип `typedef std::pair<QTreeWidgetItem *, DSKnob *>`. Наверняка это ошибка, и он должен иметь тип: `typedef std::pair<QTreeWidgetItem *, boost::shared_ptr<DSKnob>>`, как и тип, который находится строчкой выше. Банально забыли исправить, скорее всего. Ну и изменив этот тип, возможно поправить придётся то, что он затронет, т.к. `boost::shared_ptr` имеет explicit ctor, и должен создаваться явно.

Comment: Какие варианты обхода? Мне бы хотелось иметь возможность синхронизировать свои изменения  с теми у кого все работает, т.е. хочется как то поправить настройки компилятора\внести правки в код так, что бы не было проблем у остальных разработчиков.

Comment: @Bezarius, лучший вариант это писать код согласно стандарту и, по возможности, писать код со стандартными элементами(`std::shared_ptr` вместо `boost::shared_ptr`)

Comment: Добавил ссылку на репозиторий с исходником.

Comment: Я честно говоря сам не понял втф, но так как лишь недавно перешел с шарпов на плюсы, у меня подобное вызвало много wtf, подумал что это я чего то не понимаю :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, благодаря вашим объяснениям, что дальше делать с этим добром ясно :)

Comment: @Bezarius, пожалуйста.